# How do I transform a tibble into a matrix?

Tags: r, transformation, transpose, data-manipulation, tibble

I'm trying to re-arrange my data. Here's an example to illustrate--I'm hoping that there's an easy way to alter the tibble to form the matrix. The matrix could also be a tibble, though I'd want to add 'year' as factor (6th column). Ideally, you'd be able to reverse this.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(112)
n <- sample(3:36, 15, replace = T)
year <- rep(2000:2002, 5)
lic <- rep(c("imp", "proc", "rec", "whl", "ret"), 3)
d1 <- as_tibble(cbind(year, lic, n))
colnames(d1) <- c("year", "license", "n")

d1 <- d1 %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year), license = as.character(license), n = as.numeric(n))

set.seed(112)
d2 <- matrix(sample(3:36, 15, replace = T), ncol = 5, byrow = T)
colnames(d2) <- c("imp", "proc", "rec", "whl", "ret")
rownames(d2) <- c(2000:2002)
```

I'd like to be able to convert d1 to d2, ideally in a way comparable to transposing a matrix using `t()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use `pivot_wider()` from tidyr, the values to pivot wide with be provided with `values_from=` , and they will named after `names_from=` :

```
pivot_wider(d1,names_from=license,values_from=n)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
   year   imp  proc   rec   whl   ret
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000    12    35    31    26     4
2  2001    35     8    24     7    34
3  2002    33    33    34     8    17
```

Or if you like good old base R, but this works only if `year` and `license` are factors:

```
do.call(rbind,by(d1,d1$year,function(i)tapply(i$n,i$license,identity)))

     imp proc rec whl ret
2000  12    8  34  26  34
2001  33   35  24   8   4
2002  35   33  31   7  17
```

Comment: I don't think (?) this function is in the released version of tidyr (0.8.3)

Comment: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html , i am on 1.0.2 .. ok yeah i see now... hmmm you are fond of old versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spread` from `tidyr` package to do this

```
spread(d1, key = license, value = n)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
   year   imp  proc   rec   ret   whl
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2000    12    35    31     4    26
2  2001    35     8    24    34     7
3  2002    33    33    34    17     8
```